# Can not copy file from Resources folder to Documents folder

Tags: ios

[image]

Here is my code:

```
- (void)copyFileIfNeeded
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *filePath = [self getFile];
   BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
   if ( !success )
   {
        NSString *defaultFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BQWDatabase.db"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultFilePath toPath:filePath error:&error];
    }
}

- (NSString *)getFile
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BQWDatabase.db"];

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self copyFileIfNeeded];

    return YES;
}
```

But the Documents folder is always empty, how can I fix this? Thank you.

edit:

[image]

Comment: try nslog of success inside if, after copyItem...

Comment: @AnoopVaidya it's NO but I do not know why.

Comment: now print defaultFilePath and check if the file exists in this path..

Comment: The proper way to get the path to the original file in the resource bundle is: `NSString *defaultFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BQWDatabase" ofType:@"db"];`.

Comment: After calling `copyItemAtPath`, if the result is NO, then log the error.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, how can I log the error?

Comment: Really? `NSLog(@"Error is: %@", error);`.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry for that. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `BQWDatabase.db` is included in your build?  You can check by opening the right-hand pane in XCode, selecting the leftmost icon at the top, and then expanding 'Target Membership'.

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar in my own code, except I find the default file as follows:

```
NSString *defaultFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BQWDatabase" ofType:@"db"];
```

not sure whether it makes a difference